# How to transform config file without converting html encoding

Tags: xml, web-config

I am using web.config transform files to customize the web.config generated during publish of a web application based on the target environment.  One of the keys in my web.config has a value which contains html encodings (specifically using 	 for a tab character).  At publish-time, the configs are transformed, and the 	 is being converted to an actual tab.  I need the "	" to remain as it is during the transformation.  Is there a way to prevent the transformation of the web.config from decoding the characters "	"?

I've tried using "&tab;" I've tried using [CData].  This has been a on-going issue for a long time, and I've never been able to solve it.

```
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="Date &#9;Thread &#9;Level &#9;Logger &#9;Application &#9;ClientIP &#9;RemoteIP &#9;URL &#9;User &#9;EventId &#9;Action &#9;Item &#9;Security &#9;Success &#9;CaseId &#9;HttpHeaders &#9;HttpMethod &#9;SessionGUID &#13;&#10;" />
    <conversionPattern value="%date &#9;[%thread] &#9;%level &#9;%logger &#9;%message%newline" />
    <!--NOTE: &#9; is the tab character-->
  </layout>
```

Comment: You need to share with us how "...At publish-time, the configs are transformed..."

Comment: The parsing process will always convert the numeric character references or entity references into actual characters. Your only hope therefore is to convert special characters back into numeric references or entity references post-transformation. You could do that, for example, using an XSLT 2.0 serializer with character maps.

Comment: By "At publish-time", I mean in Visual Studio, when I right-click on a project and select "Publish" -- in this case a web application that I am publishing to a test and/or staging environment.  Visual Studio "Publish" command transforms the web.config file of the .net web application based on the selected build configuration for the target.